# Group Items in the ListView

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to group the items in the ListView, but it is not working:

```
        lsvChangeLog.FullRowSelect = True
    'lsvChangeLog.GridLines = True
    lsvChangeLog.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending

    Dim imageListTickAndCross As New ImageList()

    ' Initialize the ImageList objects with bitmaps.
    imageListTickAndCross.Images.Add("tick", My.Resources.tick)
    imageListTickAndCross.Images.Add("cross", My.Resources.cross)

    'Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
    lsvChangeLog.SmallImageList = imageListTickAndCross

    Dim ds As DataSet = GetCSDDetailList(False)

    Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean)
    For Each pair In dict

        Dim findTheseVals(1) As Object
        findTheseVals(0) = pair.Key
        findTheseVals(1) = "Wet"

        Dim foundRow As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Find(findTheseVals)
        Dim item As New ListViewItem
        With item
            .SubItems(0).Text = pair.Key
            .SubItems.Add(foundRow.Item(2))
        End With
        If pair.Value = True Then
            item.ImageKey = "tick"
            item.Group = lsvChangeLog.Groups("OnLine")
        Else
            item.ImageKey = "cross"
            item.Group = lsvChangeLog.Groups("OffLine")
        End If

        lsvChangeLog.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

I have two groups OnLine and OffLine, but when run items are not populated. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Listview control's ShowGroups property and make sure it's set to True... If it already is and it's still not working...

Add another Listview control and add 2 groups during design time. Add a single column and set the View property to details. Add this code quick and check if it's working... Oh and leave every name to default.

```
 Dim t As ListViewItem

 For x = 1 To 10
     t = New ListViewItem
     t.Text = x
     If (x Mod 2 = 0) Then
         t.Group = ListView1.Groups("ListViewGroup1")
     Else
         t.Group = ListView1.Groups("ListViewGroup2")
     End If
     ListView1.Items.Add(t)
 Next
```

If this works then you better check the properties of your current listview and make sure everything's set to show the grouping. If it's still not working... Delete the .exe file found inside the debug folder and compile again :)

Comment: Still doesn't work. But when I debug and check the status of ListView1, I found GroupsEnabled is set to false. But I don't see that I can enable it.

Comment: The code above does work on my side. I tested that before I posted it. There is actually no GroupsEnabled property in the default Listview Control. Are you using the default Listview?

Comment: Your code doesn't work on my side. the GroupsEnabled is not a property, when I debug and check the listView status (by highlighting the listView name and pressing the + button) after every items been added it has GroupsEnabled set to false.